# How can I enable typing indicator before a slow task, send replies with results and before stop typing indicator using Stealth?

Tags: ruby, chatbot

I'm using [Stealth](https://github.com/hellostealth/stealth) to make a chatbot to get information from a internal API.

How can I enable typing indicator before a slow task, send replies with results and after to disable typing indicator? Something like this:

```
class HellosController < BotController

  def say_hello
    # enable_typing_indicator
    # Execute a expensive task
    send_replies
    # disable_typing_indicator
  end

end
```

It's possible? make sense? another way?

Comment: Looks like you'll get help in their GH issues. https://github.com/hellostealth/stealth/issues/78

Comment: @SergioTulentsev haha Yep, I open this issue too :P. thaanksss! :D

Comment: If you get a response/help, I would post it here too, as an answer.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev nice, I'll be this.